# Is there a working code in Java to connect with Azure Keyvault to retrieve secrets using managed service identities

Tags: java, azure

I am creating an application which connects with Azure keyvault to retrieve its secrets using managed service identity.

I have tried to connect with keyvault without using managed identities and it worked but with msi, I am not able to connect.
Few things I tried:

1) This piece of code is timing out:

```
MSICredentials credentials = new MSICredentials(AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
log.debug("Credentials acquired");
KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient =  new KeyVaultClient(credentials);
log.debug("Key Vault client created");
String secret = 
    keyVaultClient.getSecret("https://<key-vault-name>.vault.azure.net/",
    "<secret-name>").value();
```

2) This piece of code is throwing error in the 1st line itself saying endpoint==null. which by looking at library means that I need to furnish MSI_ENDPOINT which I am not sure what it is.

```
AppServiceMSICredentials credentials = 
        new AppServiceMSICredentials(AzureEnvironment.AZURE);

log.debug("Credentials acquired");

    KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient =  new KeyVaultClient(credentials);

    log.debug("Key Vault client created");

    String secret = 
        keyVaultClient.getSecret("https://<key-vault-name>.vault.azure.net/",
        "<secret-name>").value();
```

Any help with this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We can use [AppServiceMsiCredential](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/credentials/AppServiceMSICredentials.html) class to achieve the result

you can read all about the param [here](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/credentials/AppServiceMSICredentials.html)

```
import com.microsoft.azure.AzureEnvironment;
import com.microsoft.azure.credentials.AppServiceMSICredentials;
import com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.KeyVaultClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.models.KeyBundle;

AppServiceMSICredentials credentials = new AppServiceMSICredentials(AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(credentials);
keyVaultClient.getSecret("https://xxxx.vault.azure.net","secretName");
```

When MSI is enabled for an App Service/any resource, two environment variables `MSI_ENDPOINT` and `MSI_SECRET` are available (note that they change every time you restart the App Service)  and can be used to obtain an access token for a given resource.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Mohit, I am kind of new to azure. I was able to access keyvault secrets without using MSI, through azure.keyvault.uri, client-id and client-key. But when I am using MSI, I am mostly lost and the documentation is sort of confusing. To start with, I have an application running in my local, I have created an app service in azure portal, enabled MSI, created a keyvault , stored some secrets there, assigned it a service principal where I selected the app service created earlier, gave it GET permissions under Secret Permissions. Now I don't know what I can do to access those secrets.

Comment: OK, I got the value of endpoint using "$env:MSI_ENDPOINT" but $env:MSI_SECRET did not return anything. Also, now I am trying to access them from deployed app in azure but I read that it can be run locally too by az login which I am not. Any help for either case.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this link to fetch database credentials from Azure Key Vault in my App Service. Used Managed Service Identity. Workekd like a charm

```
https://github.com/gandhirajan/Azure_AppService_ManagedIdentity
```